# CAST clause in ORMLite for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, casting, ormlite

I used ORMLite for Android in my application. How can I make such a query?

```
     SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE CAST(ColumnName AS INTEGER) <= 100;
```

I tried this, but it isn't work:

```
     where.le(ColumnName, 100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORMLite does not have a specific wrapper for `CAST`.

You have to [issue a raw query](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Raw-Queries).

Answer (score 3):

As @CL mentioned, ORMLite does not support `CAST`.  As s/he mentions, a raw query would work well.  An alternative would be to use the [`where.rawStatement(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#raw%28java.lang.String,%20com.j256.ormlite.stmt.ArgumentHolder...%29) as well which allows you to specify directly a part of there `WHERE` clause as a string:

```
where.rawStatement("CAST(ColumnName AS INTEGER) <= 100");
```